# Bold math letters with mathptmx package

Tags: symbols, amsmath, newtxmath, mathptmx

I'm using the package `mathptmx` for my thesis (I preferred its fonts over `newtxtext`, `newtxmath`), but I'm having some troubles with bold math symbols.

In particular, I'm trying to get a bold `X` letter (in Euler Script Font) and a bold `\Sigma` as in figure (the ones circled in green), but I can't find a way to get both at the same time: if I use `\boldsymbol` I get the X and not the `\Sigma`, if I use `\bm` from the bm package I get the `\Sigma` and not the `X`!

Any help? I tried a few other options suggested in other posts, but with no luck... If the only option is to use `newtxmath`, is there at least a way to get the `X` non-slanted? Thanks!

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,final]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
%\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

$ \boldsymbol{\mathscr{X}} $ 
$ \boldsymbol{\Sigma} $

%$ \bm{\mathscr{X}} $ 
%$ \bm{\Sigma} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`newtxmath` has an option `uprightscript` which changes the \mathscr, but the definition is a bit curious and \mathscr errors inside \bm. But you could simply switch the order of the package loading then eucal will work:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

$ \mathscr{X} \bm{\mathscr{X}}$
$ \bm{\Sigma} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I also noticed that including the package mathpazo, then \boldsymbol{\Sigma} works also with mathptmx fonts.