# How to obtain this letter

Tags: fonts

I am reading a text, in which there is this equation

[image]

The last uppercase 'X' is in Euler Script, but the first lowercase 'x'?

Comment: Possible related/duplicate? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530515/bold-math-letters-with-mathptmx-package

Comment: @Sebastiano: that question doesn't talk about lowercase letters, that are not present in euscript/eucal. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @enzotib I think that the x lowercase could be also a resize of the symbol X using scalerel package. But have you a file pdf where have you seen this image, please?

Comment: @Sebastiano: this is a page of the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u3xQMy9VrdR3JgjABxsWUpSFiEOkhRWb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As predicted, now you supply the PDF we can list the fonts, CMSL9 CMBX9 CMR10 CMSY10 CMSY10 CMMI7 CMSY7 CMMI10 CMMI10 EUSM10 EUSB7 MSBM7 CMEX10 MSBM10 CMR7   so confiming @Sebastiano's observation that these are the standard TeX computer modern AMS and Euler fonts. Although it isn't 10pt euler scaled it is the 7pt euler probably via `\scriptstyle\bm`

Comment: @enzotib Thank you very much for your pdf. My hypotesis was correct :-)- My best regards from Sicily.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much for your support to my question and to have cited my name :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano: greetings from Salerno

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For my humble opinion it is a resize of `\mathcal{X}` symbol with the option `eucal`. It is very similar to your image:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{eucal} 
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{bm}


\begin{document}
$\scaleobj{.65}{\bm{\mathcal{X}}}=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in \mathcal{X}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Peraphs with the countour package you can obtain a strong bold of the lowercase `x` or the image could to have a big resolution.

**Addendum after the comments of @barbara beeton:** Using `.60` or `.55` you have this output

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{eucal} 
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$\scaleobj{.60}{\bm{\mathcal{X}}}=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in \mathcal{X}$.

$\scaleobj{.55}{\bm{\mathcal{X}}}=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in \mathcal{X}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Having the `.pdf` file provided from the user the font identified is `eusb7` (eucal size 7).

Considering also the comment of @Steven B. Segletes "*it automatically works in the smaller math styles*":

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{eucal} 
    \usepackage{scalerel}
    \usepackage{bm}
    \newcommand{\smallx}{\scaleobj{.55}{\bm{\mathcal{X}}}}
    \begin{document}
    $\smallx =(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in \mathcal{X}$.
    $\scriptstyle{\smallx} =(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in \mathcal{X}$.
    $\scriptscriptstyle{\smallx} =(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in \mathcal{X}$.
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This hypothesis is plausible.  All four terminals match, which is uncommon.  But I think you haven't scaled it quite enough.  Try .60 or even .55.  The size should be just about correct when the top right terminal just grazes the top of the equal sign (if extended).  The apparent boldness can be attributed to the compression; nothing more should be needed.

Comment: .60 is better than .65, but \bm is needed

Comment: @barbarabeeton the OP has supplied the PDF finally: it is 7pt design font not 10pt scaled.

Comment: as it uses eusb7 (although you couldn't have known that) I suspect it is `\scaleobj{.9}{\scriptstyle\bm{\mathcal{X}}}`

Comment: I cannot see any visible difference between 0.60 and 0.90+\scriptstyle

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for your support. I have put an addendum. I'am agree with you for the size of `x` to `.55` or `.60`. Do you think that is necessary to create a specific macro...or I leave thus the answer? My best regards.

Comment: Best of all, it automatically works in the smaller math styles...you might want to show that, too.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Well, the Euler fonts are actually a single design size, and other sizes of a specific weight are definitely scaled, so without the information from the pdf file, this is actually a trick question.  (Who expects a shrunken uppercase letter to be in a position where a lowercase is assumed?)

Comment: @enzotib there may be no visible difference but the question was what is in the original and that is the 7pt bold euler font as reported by pdffonts on the PDf you provided.

Comment: @Sebastiano -- You might add an addendum reporting that the pdf file (which was finally provided) allowed the font to be identified as `eusb7`.  (I still think the usage is sneaky.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have added your excellent suggestion.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I have followed your suggestion.